# How to follow link that suppose to open in new window with click

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using the Qwebengine with PyQt5.9 and the problem is when i click url that suppose to be opened in new window it doesn't follow the link with no action in return. So how i can force it to open link in same window without right clicking and click follow link?

A simple code will be so much appreciated :)

Edit:
I tried A code like this but didn't work:

```
self.web.page().linkActivated.connect(self.visit)

def visit(self,l):
    self.web.load(QUrl(l))
```

thanks,
Max

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Honestly I searched the internet and what i came up with was only linkHovered and didnt find linkActivated method, maybe there is a work around but i am new so its bit confusing for me

Comment: Show what you have tried even if it does not work, it would also be good if you put images that describe what you want to obtain.

Comment: Added the code that i have tried with no success.

Comment: You can give me an example of a web page, and describe to me on that page what you currently get and what you want to obtain, since I do not know how to replicate your problem.

Comment: linkActivated is not a method of QWebEnginePage

Comment: I know i was just trying. Actually when for example when i try to go to yahoo.com then click on any link of its topics, none of them work because all topic links open in new window (target _blank or similar) so nothing happen at all unless i right click the link and click follow link which then take me to the topic page. I need to go to those links without right clicking and clicking follow link.

Comment: Try with my solution